# CodeIgniter calendar class won't show correct dates for +1 month

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I am trying to show three callendars, one for the current month and two for the next two months.

Here is my *commented* controller

```
public function index($year = null, $month = null, $day = null)
{
    if (empty($year)) {
        redirect('book/index/' . date('Y/m/d', time()));
    }

    $this->load->model('book/Booking_Model');

    // september
    $data['cal_one']   = $this->Booking_Model->generateCalendar($year, $month, $day);
    // october
    $data['cal_two']   = $this->Booking_Model->generateCalendar($year, date('m', strtotime('+1 months')), $day);
    // november
    $data['cal_three'] = $this->Booking_Model->generateCalendar($year, date('m', strtotime('+2 months')), $day);

    // to load the view
    $data['module'] = 'book';
    $data['view_file'] = 'select_date';
    $this->load->module('templates');
    $this->templates->frontend($data);
}
```

This is what I am getting as output

[image]

As you can see, the months are showing up correctly, however the table cells are all showing the same month, 09 (september).

If you look on the top left you can see I have var_dumped the $month variable going into the calendars and they are showing correctly, 09 ... 10 ... 11, however inside the calendar they are all the 09.

Here is my calendar model...

```
public function generateCalendar($year, $month, $day)
{
    var_dump($month);
    // styling the calendar
    $params = [
        'show_next_prev' => true,
        'next_prev_url'  => base_url() . 'schedule/index',
        'template'       => '
            {table_open}<table id="tt-calendar">{/table_open}

                {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

                    {heading_previous_cell}
                        <th class="text-center">

                        </th>
                    {/heading_previous_cell}

                    {heading_title_cell}
                        <th class="text-center" colspan="{colspan}">
                            <h4>
                                {heading}
                            </h4>
                        </th>
                    {/heading_title_cell}

                    {heading_next_cell}
                        <th class="text-center">

                        </th>
                    {/heading_next_cell}

                {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}
                {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}

                    {week_day_cell}
                        <td>
                            <strong>
                                {week_day}
                            </strong>
                        </td>
                    {/week_day_cell}

                {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}
                {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}

                    {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

                    {cal_cell_start_today}<td id="tt-calendar-today">{/cal_cell_start_today}

                    {cal_cell_start_other}<td id="tt-calendar-test">{/cal_cell_start_other}

                    {cal_cell_content}
                        <div class="day" href="" onclick="return getDate(' . $year . ' + /' . $month . '/ + {day});">
                            {day} ' . $month . '
                        </div>
                    {/cal_cell_content}

                    {cal_cell_content_today}
                        <div class="day" href="" onclick="return getDate(' . $year . ' + /' . $month . '/ + {day});">
                            {day} ' . $month . '
                        </div>
                    {/cal_cell_content_today}

                    {cal_cell_no_content}
                        <div class="day" href="" onclick="return getDate(' . $year . ' + /' . $month . '/ + {day});">
                            {day} ' . $month . '
                        </div>
                    {/cal_cell_no_content}

                    {cal_cell_no_content_today}
                        <div class="day" href="" onclick="return getDate(' . $year . ' + /' . $month . '/ + {day});">
                            {day} ' . $month . '
                        </div>
                    {/cal_cell_no_content_today}

                    {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

                    {cal_cell_other}{day}{/cal_cel_other}

                    {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}

                    {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}

                    {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}

                {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}'
    ];

    // loading the calendar and passing the params and data
    $this->load->library('calendar', $params);
    return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
}
```

If you look at the model above you can see that I am passing the `$month` variable into the model and immidiately var_dumping it to make sure that it is passing '+1 month' into the model. That is working... however I am echoing that month out in the `{cal_cell_content}` tags and am getting only this month (september) for each of the three calendars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well here's the answer for someone like me in the future.

**Cause of problem**

CodeIgniter loads libraries which are instantiated ONCE. So here I was trying to get the 'calendar' library three times, when in actual fact CodeIgniter saw that I instantiated it for september, so it did bother instantiating for october or november (singleton pattern?).

**Solution**

Thankfully CodeIgniter allows you to assign a custom class name to a library, e.g.

```
$this->load->library('calendar', $params, 'custom_name);
return $this->custom_name->generate($year, $month);
```

Pretty cool, so now all I had to do was dynamically generate a new 'name' for each of the months I wanted to display... so I made the name the `$month` variable like this.

```
$this->load->library('calendar', $params, $month);
return $this->$month->generate($year, $month);
```